# NO UBNLDR error while booting from unetbootin

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, unetbootin

I was trying to install **Ubuntu14.04.1** using Unetbootin. I downloaded the .iso file and followed the steps as outlined in the official tutorial.

However after I select the Unetbootin option from the  boot options, nothing happens. It gets stuck at this screen , which says

Try (hd0,0): FAT16: No UBNLDR

Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: _

After searching the web for this issue, I couldn't find anything conclusive. Am I missing something here?

Also, the .iso image that I downloaded has the name "**ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64** ". Can this be the cause of this? My system is a Win7 system with Intel Centrino, 3GB RAM.

I found a thread where somebody posted about the issue in Vista, and it mentioned setting the boot device correctly.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/283743

I tried to run the bcdedit command, but I'm not sure how to get the GUID of Unetbootin.

I saw another thread with the same issue that is currently unanswered :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/517574/unetbootin-ubnldr-mbr-error-during-boot-up

Can somebody help me here.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: which "official" installation instructions are you talking about? step number you got stuck in?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: I'm talking about the steps/tutorials given in Unetbootin webpage.This is the link : http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/  And the step number would be 3- after reboot when it should load the Ubuntu files and install. I get the dual boot option- Win 7 and Unetbootin, but not any further from there :(

Comment: @Fabby the link you mentioned is for installation of Ubuntu. My question, though linked with installation, is an entirely different question. I don't think it's a duplication.

Comment: The Centrino is a 32-bit Pentium-M processor, so no it **is** a duplicate.  Take especially care in step 1 of the answer.

Comment: @Fabby What do you think about the error message that says `Try (hd0,0): FAT16: No UBNLDR`? I've never used any format for a Linux live USB except FAT32, so I don't know. Also see Pedro's answer.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit CPU, you can't boot a 64-bit Ubuntu on it.

Comment: @karel: we now need feed-back from **geeko_zac** before we can proceed...

Comment: guys, I installed it correctly using a Live USB. Ubuntu up and running on my system. Thank you all for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-formatting the USB drive as FAT32. I had the same problem and after using FAT32 I can boot properly.

Comment: I doubt this will solve this specific problem.

Comment: Pedro's answer worked for me, but under different circumstances as follows. Ubuntu 14.04 live USB formatted as FAT32 doesn't boot. After reformatting the USB flash drive as FAT32 with GParted and putting the Ubuntu iso on the USB drive again, Ubuntu 14.04 live USB does boot. Somehow or other reformatting the USB fixed the problem.